# Capturar CheckBoxes marcadas em uma View

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, mvc, razor

Estou listando meus objetos por meio de uma `ViewBag` mandada para a `View`, sendo que para cada item existe uma `checkbox`, e para cada contrato existe um Id:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Contratos)
{
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="CheckBoxPessoa">
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

Como posso fazer para capturar o Id do contrato de cada `checkbox` marcada? Sendo que quero mandar essa "lista" de Id's como parâmetro para um método da controller.

Comment: Como está a sua `Controller` e como está fazendo o post para ela? Corrija pergunta com o trecho correto de código da sua view

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta mas vamos lá.
Para isso primeiro vc tem que colocar o valor no value do input

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Contratos)
{
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="entity[@i].id" value="@item.id">
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

No controller você teria:

```
public ActionResult NomedoController(entity List<Entity>) {}
```

Leia entity, como a sua classe.

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
@model List<WebMetas.ViewModels.ProdutoMetaViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Incluir - Meta";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Meta", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-responsive dt-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center col-sm-2">Descrição</th>
            <th class="text-center col-sm-2">Qtde</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            var index = 0;
            foreach (var produto in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" name="[@index].ProdutoId" id="[@index].ProdutoId" value="@produto.ProdutoId" />
                    <td>
                        @produto.Descricao
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <input type="text" class="text-right" name="[@index].Qtde" id="[@index].Qtde" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                index++;
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span> Salvar</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<ProdutoMetaViewModel> produtos)
{
   //Implementar
}
```

Segue um refeência que pode te ajudar: [link](https://duanbrito.net/2016/09/06/como-enviar-uma-lista-em-um-post-com-asp-net-mvc/)